# Diacritics in username - Windows 7 - Python

Tags: python, windows

Several months ago, I've bought a new notebook which has already installed Windows 7. The problem is probably that it's admin user name contains diacritics. I program in Python and sometimes the diacritics causes problems.

For example I can't install Python modules using **`pip`** because It raises `UnicodeDecodeError` which can be solved by using **`easy_install`**.

Now, I have a new problem. I'm trying to use `nltk module`. I've already installed it using easy_install. When I try to get synset:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
print wn.synset('big')

it raises error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/u�ivatel/PycharmProjects/PribliznostneVyhladavanie/testy.py", line 6, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.0-py2.7.egg\nltk\__init__.py", line 117, in <module>
    from nltk.align import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.0-py2.7.egg\nltk\align\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from nltk.align.ibm1 import IBMModel1
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.0-py2.7.egg\nltk\align\ibm1.py", line 18, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import comtrans
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.0-py2.7.egg\nltk\corpus\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.0-py2.7.egg\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from nltk.data              import load
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.0-py2.7.egg\nltk\data.py", line 74, in <module>
    if os.path.expanduser('~/') != '~/':
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 310, in expanduser
    return userhome + path[i:]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I assume that this could be caused by the diacritics but I'm not sure.

What should I do to avoid these problems instead of reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to python 3.4? I don't think it would have this problem as it's strings are UTF-8 encoded as opposed to ASCII encoded.

Comment: @Dunes I use Python 2.7. Unfortunately, I use some modules which can't be used in Python 3.x.